# Not able to link the google events to the google calendar using simplepie

Tags: php, rss, google-calendar-api, simplepie

I am using php include(mandatory) and simplepie for getting event title and start date, but it keeps giving me 8th august 2013 for every event. I can see the events just fine. Any idea how else to grab the 'when' tag from this?
I get error if I use tags. I am not a pro in php and at my wit's end right now!

```
       <?php
  if ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) {
     parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $arg);
  } else {
     $arg['feed'] = '';
     $arg['count'] = '';
     $arg['more'] = '';
     $arg['nodiv'] = '';
  }

  if (!isset($arg['nodiv'])) $arg['nodiv']='false';

  if ($arg['nodiv'] != 'true') {
?>





 <div id="news_list">
<?php
  }

  include('simplepie.inc');

// Let's create a new SimplePie object
$feed = new SimplePie();

$feed = new SimplePie();
  $feed->set_file($file);
  $feed->enable_cache(false);   

  $feed->init();
  $feed->handle_content_type();

// This is the feed we'll use
$feed->set_feed_url('http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/aufdccetl%40gmail.com/public/full?max-results=2');


// Let's turn this off because we're just going to re-sort anyways, and there's no reason to waste CPU doing it twice.
$feed->enable_order_by_date(false);

// Initialize the feed so that we can use it.
$feed->init();

// Make sure the content is being served out to the browser properly.
$feed->handle_content_type();

// We'll use this for re-sorting the items based on the new date.
$temp = array();


foreach ($feed->get_items() as $item) {


    // We want to grab the Google-namespaced <gd:when> tag.
    $when = $item->get_item_tags('http://schemas.google.com/g/2005', 'when');



    // Once we grab the tag, let's grab the startTime attribute
    $date = $when[0]['attribs']['']['startTime'];

    // Let's convert it all to UNIX timestamp. This will be used for sorting.
    $sortDate = SimplePie_Misc::parse_date($date);

    // Let's format it with date(). This will be the date we display.
    $gCalDate = date('l, F j, Y', $sortDate);

    // This is how each item will be displayed. We're adding it to the array we created earlier, and indexing it by the $sortDate.
    $temp[$sortDate] = '<p> <div class="event_title"><a href=' . $feed->get_permalink(). '>'  . $item->get_title() . '</a></div> <div class="event_date"> ' . $gCalDate . '</div> <br/></p>';
}

// Change this to krsort() to display with the furthest event first.
ksort($temp);

// Loop through the (now sorted) array, and display what we wanted.
foreach (array_slice($temp, 0, 3) as $paragraph) {

    echo $paragraph;

}
?>
```

This script fetches the event title and date just fine, It is not getting the public url of the event. Instead shows me a blank calendar. Any ideas on how to get public event info via the url?

Comment: What's the URL for the feed you are pulling from? Can you verify that it's a valid feed in your browser? If so, what are the article dates?

Comment: Are you sure that `$arg['feed']` is providing a valid file name that exists on the server?

Comment: I have the script working now, just need to display only 3 events instead of the entire list and I am trying to figure that out now
Also, it's a pvt feed that I can't show here.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question about limiting events/articles, use the [set_item_limit()](http://simplepie.org/wiki/reference/simplepie/set_item_limit) function. For example:

```
$feed->set_item_limit(5);  // limit each feed to the top 5 articles/events
$feed->init();
```

If you want to limit the total number that displays, use this:

```
$max_items_total = 25; // limit the total number of articles displayed to 25
foreach ($feed->get_items(0, $max_items_total) as $key=>$item) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Revent, but I got this part working. I really need to fetch individual url of each event. So, when the user clicks the event title, he is taken to event information.

Comment: You're welcome. Assuming that your feed items have the urls in them, you should be able to fetch those. You can also get the feed url if it's there.